# Superimposing gamma distribution curve to a plot

Tags: r

I have to superimpose the gamma distribution curve to a plot of others powerlaw-like curve.
I first plot dot points of the histogram in log-log scale

```
  plot(log(pp$mids),log(pp$density))
```

then i would like to superimpose my gamma distribution curve calling an external function gamma()

```
  gamma <- function(X)
  {
  n <- length(X)
  theta<-var(hh2$V1)/mean(hh2$V1)
  kappa<-mean(hh2$V1)/theta
  y<-rgamma(n,kappa,theta)
  xx<-hist(y,plot=F)
  curve(log(xx$density),add=T,col='violet',type='l')
  return( c(kappa) ) 
  }
```

but this return me an error because curve() needs a true curve to plot. How can i do this?

Comment: `curve` doesn't actually plot a true curve. It just draws a series of points along the expression and links them. You can see this if you try something like: `curve(sin(x), -2*pi, 2*pi, type="p")` Try doing something similar with your data. Make a dataframe of inputs and outputs and plot that.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to plot `dgamma(data)` ,using `curve` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat-working variant of your code:

Generate an example structured as (I guess) your data are:

```
library(rmutil)  ## for rpareto
set.seed(101)
hh2 <- data.frame(V1=rpareto(1000, m=1, s=1.5))
```

Initial histogram calculation:

```
pp <- hist(hh2$V1,plot=FALSE)
```

Function (better not to call it `gamma` as that masks a built-in function):

```
ghistfun <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)
    scalepar <- var(x)/mean(x)
    shapepar <- mean(x)^2/var(x)
    y <- rgamma(n,shape=shapepar,scale=scalepar)
    xx <- hist(y,plot=FALSE)
    lines(log(xx$mids),log(xx$density),col="red")
    curve(dgamma(exp(x),shape=shapepar,scale=scalepar,log=TRUE),
        add=TRUE,col="blue")

    shapepar
}
```

It might be better to use a very large number for `n` rather than just using the length of the data, unless you are particularly interested in seeing the random fluctuations in a data set of precisely the same size.  Alternatively you could just use `curve(dgamma(x,...))`, as shown (I initially thought that you would have to allow for scaling from a density of `x` to a density of `log(x)`, but because of the way you have computed a histogram on the original (unlogged) scale and then transformed the bin midpoints, you don't have to ...)

```
plot(log(pp$mids),log(pp$density))
ghistfun(hh2$V1)
```

[image]