# How to implement histfit in r?

Tags: r

There is histfit function in Matlab would plot histogram and fit the distribution by bin values.
The distribution's parameters have to be estimated.
How to implement histfit in r? I searched for a long time, but it has no lucky.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539) have mentioned this before, but there is no preferable solution. The sn package seems support several distribution, not so much.

I explore the data with hist function, the histogram shows gamma distribution in gerneral.
But if I add up bins and show it again, the graph will show more details, and gamma distribution fails.
fitdistr would fail to find parameters also.
so I want to fit the data just using the coarse data from histogram. This is the question, thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  Did you even bother to search here?  Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539

Comment: What I wanted is almost as @fmark described in [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539). But sn package is only suite for some distributions that is not on my list.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I need gamma distribution to be supported.

Comment: Please learn how to search. The **very first hit** of the query `[r] how to fit gamma distribution` returns this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689595 More generally, the MASS package has a function `fitdistr`

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I have read that. fitdistr fit all samples by mle method, but I want to fit by bin values hist returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to answer it myself, package 'bda' could fit the binned data in several distributions, however it could only binning data by rounding.

Answer (score 1):

The `fitdistr` function in the MASS package can be used to find parameters for a given distribution (including gamma).  The function `density` and the `logspline` package (and others) can be used to estimate the density function of the data without assuming a specific distribution.

The `lines` and `curve` functions can be used to add an estimated density curve to a plotted histogram (use `prob=TRUE` when creating the histogram).

If you want to compare your data to a specific distribution then tools like qqplots (`qqplot` function or others) or visual tests (`vis.test` in the TeachingDemos package) will probably be better than a histogram and density plot.

Comment: I have modified the description above, please check about that.

Comment: The `oldlogspline` function in the logspline package can fit an estimated density based on interval censored data (histogram bin counts), this will not be a gamma, but an estimated density.  If you want the gamma density then you can still use `fitdistr` either with just the raw data, or create a liklihood for the gamma and interval censored data (or `optim` instead of `fitdistr`). It is not clear exactly what you want and what data you have.